# Unix shell script to archive files on Remote system

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a requirement to archive files on remote location. i.e., I need to write a shell script that will connect to remote path copy(move) files from this path and then paste them on another location in the same system (The target system could be either a Unix system or a windows system).

This script will be scheduled to run once a day without manual intervention.

Comment: Look up `rsync` and/or `scp`.

Answer (score 0):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) should fit your bill. `rsync` and `scp` would work as well but they can be a bit cryptic to set up.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I would try this option and let you know the results. Thanks for the suggestion.
--Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

There are implementations of the Secure Shell (SSH) for both targeted systems. The Secure Shell comes with a secure copy program, named `scp` which would allow you to run commands like

```
scp localfile user@remotehost:directory/remotefilename
```

As lynxlynxlynx pointed out, another option is the `rsync` suite. Both SSH and rsync will require some configuration (rsync less so). See the respective home pages.

Comment: Hi Jens, I want to change the directory of the file on same remote server, this file already is on remote server. I believe we use SCP to copy files from local system to remote system. Please correct if I am wrong
--Santhosh

Comment: Executing commands remotely is done e.g. with `ssh user@host mv from to`.